# Better way to write this in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby. After a ton of refactoring I came down to this. Is there a better way to write this?

```
 51   def tri_num?(n)
 52     i = 1
 53     while i < n
 54       return i if i * (i + 1) / 2 == n
 55       i += 1
 56     end 
 57     raise InvalidTree
 58   end
```

Comment: define 'better'? You mean visually, or speed? Because if it's the latter you care about, a while loop is probably the fastest. I agree it's not too visually appealing though. Check out Fixnum#times: `n.times { |i| return i if i * (i + 1) / 2 == n` for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about solving it directly?

```
def tri_num? n

  i = (0.5*(-1.0 + Math.sqrt(1.0 + 8.0*n))).to_i

  if i*(i+1)/2 == n
    return i
  else
    raise InvalidTree
  end

end
```

Though I don't know if `tri_num?` is a good name.  Usually a function ending with a ? should return `true` or `false`.

Comment: I'm not acquainted with that equation, any reference?

Comment: I just did a little algebra and solved the [quadratic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) i^2 + i - 2*n = 0.

Comment: I wish I had math skills. Good solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
def tri_num?(n)
  1.upto(n-1) do |i|
    return i if i * (i + 1) / 2 == n
  end
  raise InvalidTree
end
```

Comment: Isn't this wasting cycles? say n is 11, which is not a triangle number: this is running up until the 10th triangle number which is 55, way above n.

Comment: My algorithm is basically the same as the one you originally posted in the question, but it is just written more concisely.  Your algorithm has the same inefficiency.  I noticed it but did not bother to improve it.  A "break" statement at the appropriate time would make this algorithm more efficient in the case where it raises an exception.

Answer (score 2):

I thought the same as dantswain, basically invert the equation:

```
=> i * (i + 1) / 2 = n
=> i * (i + 1) = 2*n
=> i^2 + i = 2*n
=> i^2 + i -2*n = 0
```

And the solutions for the above are:

```
i = (-1 +- sqrt(1+8n))/2
```

Here I don't consider the `-` solution as it will give negative for any value of n bigger than 0, in the end the code is:

```
def tri_num?(n)
    i = (-1 + Math.sqrt(1 + 8*n))/2.0
    return i.to_i if i == i.to_i
    raise InvalidTree
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def tri_num?(n)
  (1...n).each do |i|
    return i if i * (i + 1) / 2 == n
  end
  rails InvalidTree # not defined..                                             
end
```

Comment: yes.. he wanted to do go up to n-1 -- that's what the '...' syntax does, it does not include the end value. e.g. 3 dots, not 2

Comment: duh.. that was a typo! thanks for pointing that out.. i meant to type "1" of course :-P